# Extend clickCount to more than 2 items

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I am learning to create Android widget following the tutorial from https://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/android-complete-widget-tutorial-including-source-code/

Tutorial showed how to build android widget with one button and image. Button press will change the image displayed.

```
public class MyWidgetIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static int clickCount = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("pl.looksok.intent.action.CHANGE_PICTURE")){
        updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(context);
    }
}

private void updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(Context context) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_demo);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_image, getImageToSet());

    //REMEMBER TO ALWAYS REFRESH YOUR BUTTON CLICK LISTENERS!!!
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, MyWidgetProvider.buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

    MyWidgetProvider.pushWidgetUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(), remoteViews);
}

private int getImageToSet() {
    clickCount++;
    return clickCount % 2 == 0 ? R.drawable.me : R.drawable.wordpress_icon;
}
```

}

What I want to do is to extend the `clickCount` to multiple (12 images). The author commented that:
Put drawables in an ArrayList and after button click get the drawable corresponding to clickCount
Remember to reset counter if it reaches ArrayList’s size to avoid IndexOutOfBounds exception

But I really have no idea on how to do this since I have only beginning knowledge in Java and Android development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I made it:

```
public class MyWidgetIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static int clickCount = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("com.example.intent.action.CHANGE_PICTURE")){
        updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(context);
    }
}

private void updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(Context context) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_demo);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_image, getImageToSet());

    //REMEMBER TO ALWAYS REFRESH YOUR BUTTON CLICK LISTENERS!!!
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, MyWidgetProvider.buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

    MyWidgetProvider.pushWidgetUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(), remoteViews);
}

private int getImageToSet() {

    clickCount++;
    if (clickCount == 1) {
        return R.drawable.image1 ;
    }
    if (clickCount == 2) {
        return R.drawable.image2 ;
    }
    if (clickCount == 3) {
        return R.drawable.image3 ;
    }
    clickCount = 0;
    return R.drawable.image4 ;
}
}
```